# Find the vector pointing up a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Given a 3d normal vector I want to find the normal vector with the maximum y value.

I'm currently thinking about this as a disk with radius 1, where I need to find the maximum point on the disk (assuming the disk isn't flat) but I can't come up with a clean way to find this vector.

I think I could use the Simplex algorithm to find the point but this seems overkill / more complicated then it needs to be.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n$ be the vector that is normal to the plane of the disc, then in spherical coordinates

$ n = ( \sin \theta \cos \phi, \sin \theta \sin \phi, \cos \theta ) $

Two vectors that span the rim of the disc are

$ u_1 = ( \cos \theta \cos \phi, \cos \theta \sin \phi, -\sin \theta )$

and

$u_2 = ( - \sin \phi, \cos \phi , 0 ) $

So that now any point of the rim can be expressed as

$ P = \cos \psi \ u_1 + \sin \psi \ u_2 $

The maximum $z$ of $P$ occurs when $\psi = \pi $, and therefore the vector you're looking for is just $(- u_1) $

$N = - u_1 = (- \cos \theta \cos \phi, - \cos \theta \sin \phi, \sin \theta ) $